# Having trouble with Async and Location Listener

Tags: c#, xamarin, geolocation, async-await, object-reference

I've looked though MSDN and here and I have tried a bunch of different ways of doing this and none work. I am trying to start the listener for James Montemagno's geolocator plugin for Xamarin. Even using his exact code, I am totally stuck.

I think there must be something I am just completely missing about await.async and maybe just OO programming in C# in general. I'm new to Xamarin and C# so I'm struggling a bit. I have a class called LocationControls.cs that looks like this

```
using EIOBoardMobile.Model;

namespace EIOBoardMobile.CustomControls
{

    public static class LocationControls
    {
        public static async Task StartListening()
        {

            if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
                return;


            await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), 10, true);

            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += PositionChanged;
            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError += PositionError;

        }

        private static void PositionChanged(object sender, PositionEventArgs e)
        {
            GPSLocationCurrent.SetLatLong();
        }

        private static void PositionError(object sender, PositionErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e.Error);
            //Handle event here for errors
        }

        private static async Task StopListening()
        {
            if (!CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
                return;

            await CrossGeolocator.Current.StopListeningAsync();

            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged -= PositionChanged;
            CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError -= PositionError;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to start the listener immediately when the app opens. so my App.xaml.cs looks like this.

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {

    public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
            if (Settings.LocationTracking == true)
            {
                await LocationControls.StartListening(); 
                //this is where I'm getting the error
            }
        }
```

The error says I can only use await with an async method. But then if I try not to use await it says I can't use the method without the await keyword.

I have tried this also with out the static keywords but then it says it needs an object reference. But then when I try to create an object reference it says it doesn't return anything. Every different way I try it I get an error. I just want to be able to start the listener immediately. I realize the return statement after the if in StartListening() prevents me from giving the StartListening() method a return type but I don't want a return type anyway. I need a way to not run StartListeningAsync if it's already listening so I need that return.

I am so lost on the Async methods. Maybe if I just understood how to do an object reference for non-static methods that would help. But I've tried using variables and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors can't be async, so calling async methods within them can be problematic.  The easiest workaround would be to call it from the App's [OnStart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle#lifecycle-methods)(), which can by async

```
protected async override void OnStart()
{
    if (Settings.LocationTracking == true)
            {
                await LocationControls.StartListening(); 
            }
}
```

Comment: Dude. I haven't compiled it yet but the editor is giving me no errors now. You are the man.

Maybe you can answer another question for me. Static methods are still considered async right? I have another one that seems to be ok as far as any errors but it's not requiring me to use await even though the method is defined with the async keyword.

Comment: This compiled no problem. Ran into an error with permissions but that confirms the code is calling the method. You rock dude. Thanks.